# Permission denied when trying to link pycharm to dockerized django venv

Tags: python, django, pycharm, virtualenv

I'm trying to connect pycharm to the django dockerized venv but pycharm get an error about permission denied. "Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/usr/src/qatrackplus/deploy/docker/user-data/.venv": permission denied: unknown"

I already tried to chmod +777 the venv folder in case of rights problem but, pycharm still can't access it...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to point .../.venv/bin/python and not just .../.venv/ (int the docker file system btw). Why pycharm returned me permission error still haunt my mind but that works now :).

Comment: Please add the answers like yours as a comment